# SSH service not working after fresh restart

Tags: ssh, authentication, reboot

I have a ASUS Tinker Board. I have been customizing the provided Debian image so that I can use the board. However, the SSH service never works after a fresh boot, until I login to the server physically and restart the SSHD service manually. I wanted to see if there is a solution.

Comment: [u&l] is a better home for this.

Comment: What version of Debian is the provided image running?

Comment: Currently, the system is running 9.2 Debian.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have sshd enabled to start at boot?

```
systemctl enable ssh
```

Also, look in the log files to see if there are additional messages of why the processing may have been not started. Or if the above doesn't work, use the logs for further trouble-shooting.

Answer (score 0):

With update-rc.d you should be able to install your sshd init script.

```
update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

For more information about update-rc.d in Debian please visit [this Debian manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/sysv-rc/update-rc.d.8.en.html)

Comment: depending on the debian version this might not be the optimal approach due to systemd

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can add

> service sshd restart

under

> /etc/init.d

Comment: depending on the debian version this might not be the optimal approach due to systemd